# Subsection only in even header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Starting from the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{standardstyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\large\raisebox{.1cm}{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\large\raisebox{.1cm}{\rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[RE]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{standardstyle}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. #1}{}}
\chapter{test chapter}
\section{test section}
\subsection{test subsection}
   \lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

How can I put the subsection number and name into the even header instead of the section name?

Comment: novermind, found it, it's: `\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\thesubsection. \markright{#1}{}}`. Still, could someone explain this code?

Answer (score 3):

The contents of `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` is determined by the commands `\markboth` and `\markright`, that usually are issued by sectioning commands such as `\chapter` or `\section`.

There is an additional level, though. When you do `\chapter{Title}`, among other things LaTeX issues `\chaptermark{Title}`; similarly `\section{Title}` and `\subsectiontitle` issue `\sectionmark{Title}` and `\subsectionmark{Title}`.

Usually the definition of `\chaptermark` contains `\markboth{<code>}{}` which sets the `\leftmark` to `<code>`  (the second argument would set the `\rightmark`), while `\sectionmark` usually contains `\markright{<code>}`.

The standard definition of `\subsectionmark` is “do nothing”.

Thus, if you want the current subsection number and title in the header, you should define

```
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection. #1}}
```

You probably should have also

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection. #1}}
```

in order not to have an empty header if there is no current subsection, but there is a current section.